# Where is the proper place to set contentOffset in UIScrollView sub-class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am working on a view which inherits from `UIScrollView`, and the requirement is that it should start at a `contentOffset.y` position that is dependent on the view size. Specifically I want to start one screen down in a content that is 3 x the view height. 
Like this:

```
- (void)configureStartCondition {
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height * 3.0);
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, self.bounds.size.height * 1.0);
}
```

The view itself is wired up with constraints in **Storyboard**, just like any view. As it works, the framework will initially give the view the size it has in the storyboard, then when the device size is known, the view's size will be changed to its final size. This is how it should work, and I am fine with this. My question is where do I call `configureStartCondition`?

An obvious solution would be to put this code in `setFrame:`, but it doesn't work. `setFrame:` is only called for the initial frame size, which might or might not be the final size. Why is this?

```
// NOT working
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self configureStartCondition];
}
```

A more common place would be in `layoutSubview`, where I usually do this kind of setup. However, as it is a `UIScrollView` the `layoutSubview` is called *very* frequently as the user scrolls the view. Meaning I would need to save the last height and compare it to make things work, then run through this test millions of times just to be able to initialize. It feels like a kludge to me.

```
// Working, but ugly
- (void)layoutSubview {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.bounds.size.height != self.savedHeight) {
        self.savedHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
        [self configureStartCondition];
    }

    // Do layout stuff
}
```

Another place that may seem good is `setBounds:`. It *will* get called for the view size change, but since the `contentOffset` property is tied to the `bounds` property, I actually get as many calls here as to `layoutSubviews`.

So, is there a better place to do it, or a better way to do it?

Side issue, less important in my case, but can the content offset be set from a storyboard?

EDIT: Solutions in `Swift` are also fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding an observer to handle when the bounds changes?

Comment: I tried it now, but it is called exactly as much as overriding `setBounds:`, see my test of `setBounds:` above.

Comment: @rmaddy why remove the `swift` tag? I accept solutions in either language. Is this wrong use of tags?

Comment: Tags represent what you question is actually about. Your question isn't about the Swift programming language. Just because you are willing to accept answers with Swift code doesn't mean your question is about Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentSize:` works perfect for me. It called only when size changed.

PS: My code to check: (sorry for swift but UIKit make no difference)

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize{
        didSet{
            var offset = contentOffset
            offset.y = contentSize.height / 2.0
            contentOffset = offset
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but in my case, as you can see above, I set the contentSize myself, and it should be a size related to the view’s final height. Your solution would create an infinite loop.

Comment: I didn;t noticed it, sorry. You know that actually bounds had to consist of contentOffset and contentSize? So basically what you trying to do make no sense.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change "bounds"(conte size + offset) of your scroll view in some particular moment? For example when controller did `layoutSubviews` or `willAppear`?

Comment: I want to adjust `contentSize` proportional to the final view size, and then set an initial `contentOffset`. Why doesn't that make sense?

Comment: There two "final" size. External(frame) - indicates how view placed in it's container and Internal(bounds) - representing space available for it's subviews. As I understand you want change internal final size on changing of internal final size. Definitely it will case infinite loop. But you avoided it by `if (self.bounds.size.height != self.savedHeight)` You can use same condition in code I proposed. If it works on `setBounds` it will work on `setContentSize`. But content size will not change when user will scroll.

Comment: But another question is about the way you determining final size, and reason while it changing. Perhaps logic "change internal final size on changing of internal final size" require some adjustments.

Comment: Well, `contentSize` is not the same as `bounds.size`. I want to know when `bounds.size` changes, then set `contentSize` and `contentOffset` accordingly. Listening on `contentSize` will not give me bounds size.

Comment: literally `bounds` is contentOffset + contentSize. Just expose separately. Perhaps you can force UIKit to change one without changing another but it can cause unpredictable defects. As I said `bounds` is internal space. contentOffset - is bounds.offset - this is why scrolling causing change of bounds, contentSize - is bounds.size. And treated same way. But it is much more convenient to have possibility to change them separately.

Comment: I disagree. `bounds.origin` is equal to `contentOffset`, but `bounds.size` is **not** equal to `contentSize`. Please try setting up a UIScrollView with content size 500x4000, then print bounds and you will see. `bounds.size` is equal to `frame.size` with a transform set to identity, which is a viewport into the scrollable area of size `contentSize`.

Comment: Please read more about bounds and and frame https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html

Comment: Your link does not deal with scroll views. Please test this in a scroll view: set contentSize to large size, print `bounds`. You will see they are not the same.

Comment: It's about the way how UIKit works. As I said you can break it, you can ignore it. But it can end up with some problems.

Comment: But it doesn't work like that. Why not do a simple test?